# How to use case statement instead of for-loop in verilog

Tags: for-loop, verilog

The following is a seven-person voting program described in verilog, but due to the efficiency of the for loop, I would like to change the **for loop** into a **case statement**.

```
module voter7(pass, vote);

output pass;
input[6:0] vote;
reg[2:0] sum;

integer i;
reg pass;

always @(vote) 
    begin
        sum = 0;
        for(i=0; i<=6; i=i+1)
            if(vote[i]) sum = sum+1;
        if(sum[2]) pass = 1;
        else pass = 0;
    end

endmodule
```

This is the assignment left by my professor. Exactly, I would like to use case statement to rewrite the code below.

```
for(i=0; i<=6; i=i+1)
  if(vote[i]) sum = sum+1;
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Unlike different high-level programming languages like 'C', the Verilog case statement includes implicit break statements.
> [verilog-case-statement in Verilog Tutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/verilog-case-statement)

In my experience, your professor maybe made a mistake that he think Verilog can sequentially execute multiple case statements but actually it can not do that.
So, you may use a awkward method which is as follow to response your professor.

```
module voter7(pass, vote);

output pass;
input[6:0] vote;
reg[2:0] sum;

integer i;
reg pass;

always @(vote) 
    begin
        sum = 0;

        casez(vote)
            7'b??????1: sum = sum + 1;
        endcase
        casez(vote)
            7'b?????1?: sum = sum + 1;
        endcase
        casez(vote)
            7'b????1??: sum = sum + 1;
        endcase
        casez(vote)
            7'b???1???: sum = sum + 1;
        endcase
        casez(vote)
            7'b??1????: sum = sum + 1;
        endcase
        casez(vote)
            7'b?1?????: sum = sum + 1;
        endcase
        casez(vote)
            7'b1??????: sum = sum + 1;
        endcase
        
        if(sum[2]) pass = 1;
        else pass = 0;
    end

endmodule
```

Answer (score -1):

The *for* loop is not necessarily less efficient than a case statement. The issue is the '+' operator. Synthesis can try to generate 7 sequential adders in your case, affecting number of gates and timing.

One of the ideas is to create a huge case statement which lists all possible combination of 4+ bits. This will improve timing, not necessarily the number of gates.

```
casez(vote)
7'b???1111,
7'b??1?111,
7'b??11?11,
.... : pass = 1;

defalut: pass = 0;
```

The only problem is to list all possible combinations of 4 bits in a 7 bit system. I'll leave it up to you. The suggestion is to create a test bench and to compare results from the loop and the case statement.

BTW, use `always @*` instead of *always @(vote)*. make it a habbit, it will save yo from many mistakes later.

Answer (score -1):

I see that in the for loop you have just one assignment (sum = sum + 1). You can write this logic without a case statement.

```
always@(*)
begin
 sum = |vote ? sum + 1 : 'd0;
 pass = sum[2];
end
```

But if you wish to have a case statement only then see below

```
always@(*)
begin
  case(1'd1)
   vote[0] : sum = sum + 1;
   vote[1] : sum = sum + 1;
   vote[2] : sum = sum + 1;
   vote[3] : sum = sum + 1;
   vote[4] : sum = sum + 1;
   vote[5] : sum = sum + 1;
   vote[6] : sum = sum + 1;
   default : sum = 'd0;
 endcase
end
```